# Does the cond control structure allow multiple cases to be matched?

Tags: elixir

Is there something like a fallthrough feature for Elixir `cond` statements that would allow me to match for multiple cases? I want to do this to avoid repeating the same line of code. I also want to avoid a long chained logical OR `||` (disjunctive) statement in an `if` block. Right now, I'm repeating code like so:

```
cond do
  top == nil -> eval(rest, [operator | output_queue], opstack)
  top == "(" -> eval(rest, [operator | output_queue], opstack)
  compare_to(operator, top) < 0 -> # keep popping
  _-> # some catchall
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also want to avoid a long chained logical OR `||` (disjunctive) statement in an `if` block.

You don't need to switch to `if` to make use of `||` -- `cond`, unlike `case`, accepts any expression and you can join `top == nil` and `top == "("` with `||` to get what you want:

```
cond do
  top == nil || top == "(" -> eval(rest, [operator | output_queue], opstack)
  compare_to(operator, top) < 0 -> # keep popping
  _-> # some catchall
end
```

Comment: ha! Thanks! (It's been a long night)